# Multiple properties in YAML file Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

```
spring: 
   profiles: dev
spring.datasource: 
        driver-class-name: 
        password: ~
        url: ~
        username: ~
--- 
secdb: 
  profiles: dev
spring.datasource: 
       driver-class-name: ~
       password: ~
       url: ~
       username: ~
---
```

I have above two properties declared as shown in the application.yml file but when I use it in implementation class as follows.

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String URL;
```

it works and picks up the url from YML file.
but when I do as follows

```
@Value("${secdb.spring.datasource.url}")
private String URL;
```

it fails at spring boot start saying

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'secdb.spring.datasource.url' in value...
```

As, I am at beginner level. YML may be wrong but my intention is to have two data sources in the YML file and use the second one for one JDBC connection other one is default. Please, guide me through the mistake

Comment: `@Value("$(spring.datasource.url")` is invalid. Should be `@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")`. Also, YAML file is badly indented. And did you remember to activate profile `dev`?

Comment: @Andreas updated my question please, check. YML may be wrong but my intention is to have two data sources in the YML file and use the second one for one JDBC connection other one is default

Comment: The YAML in your question is invalid (the first `spring.datasource:` cannot be indented by that amount of space).  Is that really what spring-boot accepts or is this incorrect information you provided?

Comment: *"YML may be wrong"* If the YAML is wrong, the property name will not be what you intend, and your entire question is about the property not being defined. So, before doing *anything* else, **fix the YAML**.

Comment: indented the YAML file properly now.

Answer (score 3):

You have made two mistakes in your yaml file.

1. Don't use space before `---`.
2. Before your first `spring.datasource:`, there is a space. It indicates `spring.datasource:` is a subproperty of `spring:`.
3. `@Value("${secdb.spring.datasource.url}")` is absolutely not the right way. Even you active `secdb`, you also need to get the value like `@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")`.
4. I do't suggest you to use Spring profiles like `secdb: profiles: dev`. It's not a familiar way. You can use it like `spring: profiles: secdb` and active it just like `spring.profiles.active=secdb`. Or if you insist to use it that way, you need to active it like `spring.profiles.active=secdb`.

After all, if you want to use Spring profiles properties, you need to active it just like
`$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production`
or
add `spring.profiles.active=production` in application.properties.

I suggest you to read [this document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) in detail.

I will be glad if it helps.

Comment: I indented my YAML file wrongly in the question before. Now updated it correctly please check and I am activating the dev spring profile also.

Comment: Is there still something wrong when you start spring boot? In my trial, it works as you want.

Comment: Yes it still gives the `Could not resolve placeholder 'secdb.spring.datasource.url' in value...` error on spring boot start,to me can you show code sample of how it is working for you. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like your program don't find the `application.yml`. Did you put it in the source folder like `src/main/resources`? You need to make sure `application.yml` and `application.properties` exist in your `classpath`.

Comment: when I give @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String URL; its working but not @Value("${secdb.spring.datasource.url}")
private String URL so its picking up the application-dev.yml file as my active profile is dev.

Comment: I just edited the answer. And I think you need to be clear about the format of yaml file by reading some documents